# MySQL Date, Minutes Add to a value

Tags: mysql, datetime

I cant seem to get this to work, It returns Null

```
SELECT sdt, timeFor, DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(sdt), INTERVAL timeFor MINUTE) FROM tbl_day
```

The return keeps returning

```
sdt, timeFor, DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(sdt), INTERVAL timeFor MINUTE)
'0000-00-00 01:00:00', 15, ''
```

Columns Type

- sdt DATETIME
- timeFor BIGINT(20)

Any ideas

Comment: Can you show us how data in your table looks like?

Comment: Thats it, I copied and pasted it from the MysQL Query Browser. I posted it in the Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL usually returns NULL on date/time operations when column value is incomplete datetime. Something like `2010-00-05 11:22:33`, etc. Also using timestamp function on `sdt` column might not be a good idea. I'd suggest providing normal datetime value.

Comment: The output shows there are no spaces, I didnt type the output in my question this was a copy and paste from the query browser

Comment: `SELECT *, DATE_ADD(sdt, INTERVAL timeFor MINUTE) FROM schedule_day`, tried that same output

Comment: You genious it was the invalid values of the DATETIME. Thanks You